# Same protocol extension for different classes (but same baseclass)?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift-protocols

I'm having a hard time explaining the issue, so I'll try my best.

I have this code:

```swift
protocol MyListener
{
    func setupMyViewControllers()   //code I would like to share with any UIViewController that conforms to this protocol

    func receiveUpdateA()           //each protocol-conforming class should have its own implementation
    func receiveUpdateB()           //each protocol-conforming class should have its own implementation
}

//my classes hierarchy
class A: UIViewController {}
class B: UIViewController {}
class b: B {}
```

So, instead of writing duplicate code like the following:

```swift
extension A: MyListener
{
    func setupMyViewControllers()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveUpdateA(_:)), name: "receiveUpdateA", object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveUpdateB(_:)), name: "receiveUpdateB", object: nil)
    }

    //rest of protocol implementations
    func receiveUpdateA() {/*...*/}
    func receiveUpdateB() {/*...*/}
}

extension B: MyListener
{
    func setupMyViewControllers()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveUpdateA(_:)), name: "receiveUpdateA", object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveUpdateB(_:)), name: "receiveUpdateB", object: nil)
    }

    //rest of protocol implementations
    func receiveUpdateA() {/*...*/}
    func receiveUpdateB() {/*...*/}
}
```

I tried the following (with no success):

```swift
extension MyListener where Self: UIViewController
{
    func setupMyViewControllers()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveUpdateA(_:)), name: "receiveUpdateA", object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveUpdateB(_:)), name: "receiveUpdateB", object: nil)
    }
}

extension A: MyListener
{
    //rest of protocol implementations
    func receiveUpdateA() {/*...*/}
    func receiveUpdateB() {/*...*/}
}

extension B: MyListener
{
    //rest of protocol implementations
    func receiveUpdateA() {/*...*/}
    func receiveUpdateB() {/*...*/}
}
```

I thought that this way I could share the setup code, but still be able to extend the remaining "receiveUpdate" functions in separate extensions.
But I get stuck in a loop of errors. I get "Cannot use 'receiveUpdateA' as a selector because protocol 'MyListener' is not exposed to Objective-C. However, exposing it to obj-c then gives me the error that protocol extensions can't have obj-c functions.

Is there any way of achieving this without extending the entirety of `UIViewController` to `MyListener`? (I'm not even sure that would work. It seems like the core issue is the use of `Selectors`)

Comment: If the only thing to be affected by this protocol is UIViewControllers, why don't you say `protocol MyListener: UIViewController`? Just inject empty implementations of the `receiveUpdate` functions if you have to.

Comment: It seems like `protocol MyListener: UIViewController` is the same as `extension MyListener where Self: UIViewController`. Anyway I tried it, and just used a simple `extension ReviewListener` to define my "setup" function but it throws the error of `cannot use 'receiveUpdateA' as a selector because protocol 'MyListener' is not exposed to Objective-C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what Swift/XCode Version you are using right now, but the following appears to work just fine with Swift 5.7.1.

```
@objc protocol MyListener {

    func receiveUpdateA()
    func receiveUpdateB()
}

extension MyListener {
    
    func setupMyViewControllers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(receiveUpdateA),
            name: NSNotification.Name("receiveUpdateA"),
            object: nil
        )
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(receiveUpdateB),
            name: NSNotification.Name("receiveUpdateB"),
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
}


//my classes hierarchy
class A: UIViewController {}
class B: UIViewController {}

extension A: MyListener {

    //rest of protocol implementations
    @objc func receiveUpdateA() {/*...*/}
    @objc func receiveUpdateB() {/*...*/}
}

extension B: MyListener {

    //rest of protocol implementations
    @objc func receiveUpdateA() {/*...*/}
    @objc func receiveUpdateB() {/*...*/}
}
```

Even though I'd say that you shouldn't consider DRY as a religious rule, here's an alternative implementation using Apple's own equivalent to Rx:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

protocol ObservesNotificiationCenter {
    
}

extension ObservesNotificiationCenter {
    
    func onNotification(withName name: String) -> AnyPublisher<Notification, Never> {
        return NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: NSNotification.Name(name)
        ).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
}

@objc protocol ReceivesUpdates {
    func receiveUpdateA(notificiation: Notification)
    func receiveUpdateB(notificiation: Notification)
}

extension ReceivesUpdates where Self: ObservesNotificiationCenter {
    
    func setupNotifications() -> Set<AnyCancellable> {
        var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
        onNotification(withName: "receiveUpdateA")
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: receiveUpdateA(notificiation:))
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        onNotification(withName: "receiveUpdateB")
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: receiveUpdateB(notificiation:))
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        return cancellables
    }
    
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, ObservesNotificiationCenter, ReceivesUpdates {

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cancellables = setupNotifications()
        
    }
    
    func receiveUpdateA(notificiation: Notification) {
        
    }
    
    func receiveUpdateB(notificiation: Notification) {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the duplicate code  (implementation of `setupMyViewControllers()`)

Comment: I've updated my code with a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you! The first part is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not too sure I understand how this works, though. Why can't I declare the `setupMyViewControllers()` function inside the protocol declaration, but have to do it through an extension?

Comment: Also, I noticed that we don't need the `@objc` for each function implementation (I'm assuming it's implicit because of the `@objc` for the protocol itself).

Comment: Protocols cannot contain implementations, that's intended by Swift's design.

Comment: Not sure what that's in response to

Comment: To your first follow-up question. I assumed you are mixing ObjC with Swift. If that isn't the case, you don't need @objc.

Comment: Gotcha. Ultimately what I wanted to achieve is to have a default implementation of  `setupMyViewControllers()` (through an extension), as well as `func setupMyViewControllers()` inside `@objc protocol MyListener`: this way if a conforming class doesn't explicitly implement the function, it resorts to the default implementation (provided by the extension). But it seems I can't achieve this.

Comment: You can if you accept a little bit of overhead. Rename setupMyViewControllers to defaultSetupMyViewControllers, then add a function called setupMyViewControllers which you'll implement ein each of your classes by just invoking the default implementation (or any other).